# Vagrant error "Failed to mount folders in Linux guest" after halt or reload

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to use a Vagrant box from someone else, and it works fine when I first start it, but after I stop it and restart it with either `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up`, or `vagrant reload`, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

Right now, searching for this error message turns up a lot of people having trouble with a bug Virtual Box 4.3.10, but that's not the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out, upgrading the Linux kernel will cause the Virtual Box Guest Additions to stop working until they are rebuilt by running the following command in the VM

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
```

I had upgraded the kernel without thinking about it when I ran `yum update` (similar to `apt-get upgrade`) to get updates to other software.

Alternatively, if you install the `dkms` package as described [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), then the kernel module should be automatically updated when the kernel is updated.

Comment: True, if `dkms` is properly configured, it should take care of automatically rebuilding the kernel module after a kernel update.

Comment: @TerryWang Thanks, I've updated the answer to point that out. I linked to the best resource that I could find on dkms, but feel free to change the link if there's a better one.

Comment: It's `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` on my system now.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue virtual box addition has to be installed. For example, I use Centos 7. Firstly download centos 7 minimal and then install guest addition, please see all steps below

1. Download centos 7

   vagrant init centos/7

   vagrant up

   vagrant ssh
2. Install Guest addition for virtual box

   yum update

   reboot

   vagrant ssh

   yum update kernel

   reboot

   vagrant ssh

   yum groupinstall "Development tools"

   yum install kernel-devel

   yum install wget

   wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.2/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.2.iso

   sudo mkdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions

   sudo mount -o loop,ro VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.2.iso /media/VBoxGuestAdditions

   sudo sh /media/VBoxGuestAdditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   rm VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.2.iso

   sudo umount /media/VBoxGuestAdditions

   sudo rmdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions

   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup

   sudo chkconfig --add vboxadd

   sudo chkconfig vboxadd on

   exit
3. Package new box

   vagrant package --base my-virtual-machine

Comment: +1 Running a CentOS machine. Was unable to get the latest VBoxGuestAdditions tools, or mount my shared folder.
For me, I needed to only follow your instructions until mounting the VBoxGuestAdditions - my VM was already up to date for kernel / dev tools.
Once the ISO was mounted, running `vagrant reload` worked, using the mounted drive to install the missing tools.

Answer (score 2):

Hit the same issue, but with a different fix: I already had dkms installed (virtualbox-guest-dkms under Debian Jessie).

The thing was that the module «vboxsf» wasn't loaded automatically, and running `mount shared_directory` didn't work (`No such file or directory` error).

But after running `modprobe vboxsf`, the mounting was fine.

So I edited `/etc/modules` and appended `vboxsf` on a new line: problem solved!

Side note: if running `modprobe vboxsf` ends up on a error, you don't have the vboxsf module installed, so you should install DKMS module first.

Answer (score 2):

Right after I got the same error I did this:

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ sudo apt-get update
$ exit
```

then installed vagrant-vbguest

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

then

```
$ vagrant halt
$ vagrant up
```

and it worked!

Looking at the logs it seems that vagrant-vbguest did some cleanup in terms of vbguest additions on the guest (the VM).

```
[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (4.3.38) and guest (4.3.10) do not match.
 * Stopping VirtualBox Additions
   ...done.
rmmod: ERROR: Module vboxsf is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module vboxguest is not currently loaded
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox-guest-dkms* virtualbox-guest-utils* virtualbox-guest-x11*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
After this operation, 12.1 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 113238 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-guest-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
Removing virtualbox-guest-x11 (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-guest-x11 (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Removing virtualbox-guest-utils (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-guest-utils (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
dkms is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.13.0-91-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Copy iso file /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount: block device /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 4.3.38 - guest version is 4.3.10
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.3.38 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...done.
```

P.S. I'm on OS X using the following software versions:

```
$ vagrant plugin list
solve (0.8.2)
  - Version Constraint: 0.8.2
vagrant-berkshelf (4.1.0)
vagrant-hostmanager (1.5.0)
  - Version Constraint: 1.5.0
vagrant-hostsupdater (1.0.2)
vagrant-omnibus (1.3.1)
  - Version Constraint: 1.3.1
vagrant-proxyconf (1.2.0)
  - Version Constraint: 1.2.0
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
vagrant-vbguest (0.12.0)

$ VBoxManage --version
4.3.38r106717

$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.8.4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This took care of the problem for me. The vagrant-vbguest plugin installed the kernel and kernel-devel packages, and then updated the Guest Additions.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the Vagrant plugin [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest), it can keep your VirtualBox Guest Additions up to date.

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same error using Vagrant 1.8.1, VirtualBox 5.0.18, Chef 12.10.10 host MacOSX El Capitan and guest CentOS7.
I tried installing kernel-devel inside the guest, installing the latest GuestAdittions and updating yum, but none of these worked for me, so I changed the mount type for "nfs" in both my custom synced folders and chef temporary folder, and it worked!

In Vagrantfile, my synced folders:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

and my chef_solo config:

```
chef.cookbooks_path = ["chef/cookbooks/"]
chef.synced_folder_type = "nfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox 5.18 fixes this problem. It exists in 5.16 and can't be fixed by any usual means. The newest release 5.18 works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow issue on MAC is apparently caused by the vagrant plugin version `vagrant-vbguest-3.0`.

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

umount /mnt

Stdout from the command:

umount: /mnt: not mounted

Stderr from the command:
```

To resolve that reinstall the plugin with version 0.21

```
# uninstall
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest

# install with version 0.21
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest --plugin-version 0.21
```